Google Firebase Authentication Not Working After Changing API Key
I recently updated the Firebase API key for my Android and iOS apps using the Google Cloud Console. After making the changes, I replaced the configuration files:

Android: Updated the google-services.json file.
iOS: Updated the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

However, the Google Authentication service has stopped working. I've already tried the following:
Rebuilding and redeploying the app with the updated configuration files.
Verifying that the API key is correct and active in the Google Cloud Console.
Checking that the Identity Toolkit API and Firebase Authentication API are enabled.
Confirming the SHA-1 fingerprints for the Android app in the Firebase Console.
Ensuring the OAuth client IDs for both Android and iOS are properly configured.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. One additional challenge is that my debug console doesn’t return any specific errors or logs related to the issue.
Here are some additional details:

Framework: Flutter
Authentication Method: Google Sign-In.
Dependencies: Firebase SDKs are up-to-date.


Try to regenerate a new SHA-1 fingerprints. Because Google Firebase Authentication and App SHA-1 fingerprints are one-to-one correspondence.
